# Laravel Compare Multiple Many-to-many Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7, eloquent-relationship

I am using Laravel Eloquent to retrieve data. This is what my database looks like.

I have the user's preference in one pivot table and the agency's preference in the other:

[image: ojoi]

Can anyone help me come up with an Eloquent command that will return all the users that have at least same preferences as the agency?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query function like this, where you will get the id user with 'agency' field duplicated

```
Route::get('duplicates', function () {


$results = \App\Users::whereIn('id', function ( $query ) {
 $query->select('id')->from('users')->groupBy('agency')->havingRaw('count(*) > 1');
   })->get();
   return $results;
 });
```

I hope this help you